# React table appending empty row when new item is added to state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, state, crud

When I add a new item to a table in React, I update the state, but the table does not re-render with the new data. I know the data is being passed through, because the new item appears in the state, and a new row is appended, but all the `props.children` of the table are empty.

Here is a simplified version of the parent component.

```
class Page extends Component {
  initialState = {
    users: [],
  }

  state = this.initialState

  async componentDidMount() {
    const users = await getDataFromApi()

    this.setState({ users })
  }

  addRow = user => {
    this.setState({ users: [...this.state.users, user] })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <AddModal addRow={this.addRow} />
        <Table data={this.state.users} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

The add user modal is posting to the API (successful) and

```
handleSubmit = async event => {
  event.preventDefault()

  const response = await postDataToApi()
  const user = await getNewUser(response)

  addRow(user)
}
```

So the API gets updated successfully, the new user is read successfully, the data is getting added to state successfully, and the new row that is added has the correct ID, but the prop children of the table are empty, so the front end just shows an empty row.

Table component - I've used both a custom table wrapper over semantic UI and `react-table`, and the issue persists either way.

```
class Table extends Component {
  render() {
    const { data } = this.props

    return (
      <DataTable
        data={data}
        meta={column keys and values}
      />
    )
  }
}

class DataTable extends PureComponent {
  state = {}

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({ data: nextProps.data, meta: nextProps.meta })
  }
  ...etc
```

Edit: I was not sending the data through in the right format.

Comment: Don't use both `await` and `then`

Comment: Could you show the Table component code?

Comment: @Bergi how will I get the response of the operation? I need to the get ID of the newly added user.

Comment: @tania `const response = await postDataToApi();` ...

Comment: @JonasWilms I updated the question with some table info.

Comment: @JonasWilms Thank you, I removed the `then`.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You say "the `props.children` of the table are empty", but in your example the `Table` doesn't have any children. It only has a `data` prop. We can probably help you more if you could provide a minimal runnable test case. (e.g. on https://stackblitz.com/)

Comment: I mean the text nodes of the `td` in that row are empty. When I use React DevTools to inspect the row, that data should be in `props.children` which I assume is part of `react-table` and/or Semantic React UI.

Comment: @RomGrk I made a very simplified one: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-m1rgmb

Comment: why is `DataTable` a statefull component ? Why not a simple stateless component with two props `data` and `meta` ? Can you show us the code of this component ?

Comment: @TaniaRascia does that minimal test case exhibits the issue? This is what I see: https://ibb.co/hDvOQK and https://ibb.co/hohRee
Otherwise, what are you expecting to see in the `props.children` of the `td` node?